# Reduce div width to size of child paragraphs and image

Tags: html, css

So I have this kind of structure:

```
<div class="caption">
    <img src="...">
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>SomethingElse</p>
    <p>SomethingElseAgain</p>
</div>
```

Every paragraph *MUST* be in its own line, justified to the left, and my `.caption` div must not take any more horizontal space than its children need.

I tried with
`.caption { display: inline-block; }` but that doesn't reduce the caption div at all.

I tried adding `float: left` to `div.caption` children, but all `<p>` tags got jumbled in one line.

How should I do this? I'm using plain html+css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content) you can simply use `fit-content`:

```css
.caption {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
    <img src="...">
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>SomethingElse</p>
    <p>SomethingElseAgain</p>
</div>
Something else
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="caption">
    <img src="...">
    <p>Something</p>
    <p>SomethingElse</p>
    <p>SomethingElseAgain</p>
</div>

<style>
 .caption {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
 }
 .caption img {
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
 }
 .caption p {
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
 }
</style>
```